# Changing adf_publish branch and path in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template, azure-git-deployment

To change the publish branch in ADF (default is adf_publish), that is, the branch where Resource Manager templates are saved, add a publish_config.json file to the root folder in the collaboration branch as [explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#configure-publishing-settings). File contents being:

```
{
    "publishBranch": "factory/adf_publish"
}
```

And a refresh on ADF will show 'factory/adf_publish' as the new branch. And on publish, the arm templates are saved to the root of the branch(name of the template folder being the same name as ADF). But putting this on root folder is not how I would like to organize my branch.

```
{
    "publishBranch": "factory/adf_publish"
    "publishFolder": "Root/ARM/" // not possible!
}
```

How can I control the folder path where the ARM template folder is created?

Comment: There is a feature request here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/39560182-publish-azure-data-factory-arm-templates-to-a-cust